# Magento2 eav queries issue

Tags: magento-2.1, product, attributes

I have below queries on my pages for each attribute, It become more than 11000 request in my magento2 pages. any body can help me?

```
SELECT eav_attribute.*
FROM eav_attribute
WHERE (eav_attribute.attribute_id='70')
SELECT eav_entity_type.additional_attribute_table
FROM eav_entity_type
WHERE (entity_type_id = :entity_type_id)
SELECT catalog_eav_attribute.*
FROM catalog_eav_attribute
WHERE (attribute_id = :attribute_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perform SQL joins to reduce multiple requests to SQL server. In your case you could write query as

> ```
> SELECT eav_attribute.*, eav_entity_type.additional_attribute_table, catalog_eav_attribute.*
> FROM eav_attribute LEFT JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_attribute.entity_type_id
> LEFT JOIN catalog_eav_attribute ON catalog_eav_attribute.attribute_id = eav_attribute.attribute_id
> WHERE eav_attribute.attribute_id ='70'
> ```

If you wanna get information of multiple attributes in single request you could write as

> ```
> SELECT eav_attribute.*, eav_entity_type.additional_attribute_table, catalog_eav_attribute.*
> FROM eav_attribute LEFT JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_attribute.entity_type_id
> LEFT JOIN catalog_eav_attribute ON catalog_eav_attribute.attribute_id = eav_attribute.attribute_id
> WHERE eav_attribute.attribute_id IN ('70', '71')
> ```

Hope it finds you helpful.

Comment: Thanks, in which file should i do it? I dont know where is it. Know that in eav module it hapends but don't know what shoul i do